# error datatype mismatch in c#

Tags: c#

using insert query
when I'm writing the code

```
int ans = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

in this line it is showing error data type mismatch

Comment: Can you elaborate and provide your command & parameters?

Comment: First of all, welcome to Stack Overflow :) Secondly, you need to brush up on your question-posing skills. You need to tell us more about the problem. Do you get a compiler error? If so, post the message you get from the compiler. Or do you get a runtime exception? If so, can you post the full exception details (exception class name, message, possibly stack trace if you have it). In short, you should post as much information as you have/can.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide some more details. Can you capture the stack trace of the exception?

The error could be to do with your SQL insert statement.

In the past when I've seen errors like this developers have been using a string to build up their SQL insert and missed something simple like quoting a sql string (varchar nvarchar etc.) value correctly.

If you are building up a string like this I'd recommend changing your code to use a parametrized query or stored procedure.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 0):

Looks like either one of your input parameters is the wrong type, or the actual insert query itself is failing.  To test the latter use SQLProfiler and find the actual query running against the database.  Get this working on its own first and the check your C# paramaters

Answer (score 0):

Are you using **parametrized query**? If yes than check the datatype of parameters you send to database and what actually are in the database. I think you are sending wrong data type.