# Insert record into Access 2000 database in C#

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

I need to insert a record in Access 2000 database using C#. The code fails at the SqlConnection. Please help.

```
        string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Trading.mdb";
        string commandText = "INSERT INTO Order (OpenDate) VALUES (@OpenDate)";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OpenDate", DateTime.Now);

            try
            {
                command.Connection.Open();
                int response = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: {0}" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It didn't go to the code after SqlConnection.

Comment: First of all, I would like to thank everyone who posted their suggestions. It set me thinking and I have figured out the solution although after reading many posts and trial-and-error those sample codes.

Comment: I want to ask why my post is put on hold. What about this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415703/error-datatype-mismatch-in-c-sharp? Why isn't it put on hold or any kind of restraint? Why the double standard here?

Answer (score 3):

**Problem :** you are working with MS-Access Database but using SqlServer objects.

**Solution :** you need to use `OleDbConnection` object instead of `SqlConnection` and `OleDbCommand` instead of `SqlCommand`

Try This:

```
    string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Trading.mdb";
    string commandText = "INSERT INTO Order (OpenDate) VALUES (?)";

    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(commandText, connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OpenDate", DateTime.Now);

        try
        {
            command.Connection.Open();
            int response = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: {0}" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need [OleDbConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) not `SqlConnection` which is used for SQL Server.

See: [Walkthrough: Editing an Access Database with ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971485.aspx)

also: [How to: Create Connections to Access Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ybdbtte%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)